# How to do the scd in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, scd

I want to do the SCD process in MySQL, I have two tables which is exactly same, the table1 always truncated and it have only the new record. The table2 gets the record from table1 and it maintain the history. 
In my scenario if the existing data comes in table1 I want to overwrite in table2 and if new record comes in table1 I want to insert as a new record in table2.

```
create table table1(id int, name varchar(2),title varchar(10));
create table table2(id int, name varchar(2),title varchar(10));
```

This is my above sample table structure. If table contains value like (1,a,hockey) then I just want to insert these data into table2, then table1 will truncated. If I again inserted record to table2 with same Id but title may change In this scenario I want to overwrite the data in table2, If any new Id will come then it inserted as a new row in table2. Please explain how to do this scenario?

Comment: It seems you want do do an `UPSERT`.

Answer (score 1):

You do it in five steps:

1. Start a database transaction.
2. Select the row from `table1` into variables `id2`, `name2`, and `title2`.
3. Insert or update on `table2` using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`:

   ```
   insert into table2 (id, name, title) values (id2, name2, title2)
     on duplicate key update
       name = name2,
       title = title2
   ```
4. Delete from `table1`. Do not truncate. Truncating could void the transaction.
5. Commit the transaction.

Comment: I tried this way but I'm getting error like "Result consisted of more than one row" create procedure incremental ()BEGIN
declare id2 int;
declare title2 varchar(2);
select sid,stitle into id2,title2 from stbl;
insert into dtbl (did, dtitle) values (id2, title2)
  on duplicate key update
    sid = did,
    stitle = dtitle;
END

Comment: I have multiple rows in table1